# Search on <object data>

Tags: javascript, html

I need to perform a search for a particular word in a file that i have embedded using

```
  <object data = "".....>
```

How am i able to reference the

```
  <object data>
```

just like in

```
    <iframes>...

   window.frames['iframe id'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [getElementsByTagName](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/met_document_getelementsbytagname.asp)?  My quick test:

```
<object data="http://www.google.com"></object>
<object data="2"></object>
```

And:

```
<script>
var el = document.getElementsByTagName('object');

console.log( el[0].data ); // http://www.google.com
console.log( el[1].data ); // http://localhost/2
</script>
```

Comment: @Kuttu: I'm pretty sure you can't access the content (at least not this way). What 'file' are you embedding?

Comment: It is a file from another site.. a html file.. I used an <iframe> but i need to do the same using <object>....

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_object.asp - "The <object> tag is used to include objects such as images, audio, videos, Java applets, ActiveX, PDF, and Flash into a webpage."

Comment: I'm probably not understanding your problem.  I think you were on the right track with the iframe.  You should be able to access the DOM the way you specified.

Comment: <iframe width="100%">  Can you explain or present an example of what you're trying to search?

Comment: suppose i have a list of names in the iframe. I need to receive an input from the user, check it in the iframe and the present it seperately